# Q-value keeps stepping down when training a DQN

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, pytorch

I am training a DQN and the Q-value keeps going down. The curve looks very weird (see below).

[image]
[image]

Every step corresponds to an update to target network.
Any possible reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Does the step correspond to the Target Q network update? If so try to:

1) update the TargetQ network less frequently

2) increase the discount factor (e.g. to .99 if you were using .5)

3) use a smooth update for the TargetQ network in the form (1 - tau)*old + tau*v1